# Riemann Integral in terms of step function

Tags: integration, riemann-integration

It is seen that, if $f(x)$ is  a bounded real valued function, then  $\displaystyle \overline{\int_a^b }  f(x)\;  dx=  \inf \int_a^b \psi(x) dx \; $ where infimum is taken for all step functions $\psi(x)\ge f(x)$.
Why we take all step functions  $\; \psi(x)\ge f(x)$

Comment: Why not? What would you propose instead?

Comment: @JoshuaRuiter Sir I would like to know why we take step functions

Comment: @JoshuaRuiter we already defined upper integral as $\inf S$ where S=\Sum_{i=1}^n M_i (x_i-x_{i-1}$ where $M_i= Sup f(x) ,x\in [x_{i-1},x_i]$

Comment: @SeenaV it's because we already know how to integrate step functions, and it is quite easy, whereas we have not defined how to integrate arbitrary functions.